# I want to implement a tree-based regression model using rss

Tags: python, tree, regression, decision-tree

1.2 RSS
As stated in chapter 8 of the textbook, we need a parameter to measure the eﬃciency of a speciﬁc split/tree. We choose here Residual Sum of Squares. Implement RSS calculation for the list of splits, knowing that the value to predict (Wage(k)) is contained in element[-1] for element in split.
You can use the cell of code below your implementation to check your result on a speciﬁc split.

1.3 Split
We will code a split function capable of splitting the data in two part based on the index of the feature, the value of splitting and the data. Implement the condition of splitting, taking as convention left

1.4 Optimal split creation
There is no theoritecal result allowing to ﬁnd the best possible split before going through all the possible one, so we implement a RSS minimizer over the whole split. Using previously coded functions, ﬁll the #TODO parts. You can check your return in the following cell.

1.5 Tree Building and prediction
Aggregating all the parts of the code now allows us to build the whole tree recursively. Comment the given code, and especially the importance of the parameter min_size in regard to the model structure
Using the same coding paradigm allows us to use our model to do regression on the test set, as you can see in the next cell of code. Which part of the global model is now missing ? Explain its importance in a real machine learning problem. (Bonus) Implement it

I want to implement a tree-based regression model using rss. I want to fill out the following blanks but it is too difficult

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math

data = pd.read_csv("Wages.csv", sep=";")

training_set = np.array(data[:10])
test_set = np.array(data[10:])


-- RSS --

verbose = False
def RSS(splits):
    """
    Return the RSS of the input splits. The input should be in the form 
of a list of list
    """
    residual = 0
    for split in splits:
        if(len(split) != 0):
            mean = mean(split[:-1])
            if(verbose):print("Mean :" + str(mean))
            residual = ##TODO
    return residual

split_1 = np.array([[[0,2],[0,8]],[[4,5]]])
RSS_value = RSS(split_1)
if (type(RSS_value) not in [int,float,np.float16,np.float32,np.float64]):
    print("TypeError : check your output")
elif(RSS(split_1) == 18.0):
    print("Your calculations are right, at least on this specific 
example")
else:
    print("Your calculations are wrong")


-- Split --

def split(index, value, data):
    """
    Splits the input @data into two parts, based on the feature at @index 
position, using @value as a boundary value
    """
    left_split = #TODO condition
    right_split = #TODO condition
    return [left_split, right_split]


-- optimal split creation

def split_tester(data):
    """
    Find the best possible split possible for the current @data.
    Loops over all the possible features, and all values for the given 
features to test every possible split
    """
optimal_split_ind, optimal_split_value, optimal_residual, optimal_splits = -1,-1,float("inf"),[] #Initialize such that the first split is better than initialization
for curr_ind in range(data.shape[1]-1):
    for curr_val in data:
        if(verbose):print("Curr_split : " + str((curr_ind, curr_val[curr_ind])))
        split_res = #TODO (comments : get the current split)

        if(verbose):print(split_res)
        residual_value = #TODO (comments : get the RSS of the current split)

        if(verbose):print("Residual : " + str(residual_value))
        if residual_value < optimal_residual:
            optimal_split_ind, optimal_split_value, optimal_residual, optimal_splits = curr_ind,\
                                                                curr_val[curr_ind], residual_value, split_res

return optimal_split_ind, optimal_split_value, optimal_splits



-- tree building --


def tree_building(data, min_size):
    """
    Recursively builds a tree using the split tester built before.
    """
    if(data.shape[0] > min_size):
        ind, value, [left, right] = split_tester(data)
        left, right = np.array(left), np.array(right)
        return [tree_building(left, min_size), tree_building(right, 
min_size),ind,value]
    else:
        return data


tree = tree_building(training_set,2)




def predict(tree, input_vector):
    if(type(tree[-1]) != np.int64):
        if(len(tree) == 1):
            return(tree[0][-1])
        else:
            return(np.mean([element[-1] for element in tree]))
    else:
        left_tree, right_tree, split_ind, split_value = tree
        if(input_vector[split_ind]<split_value):
            return predict(left_tree, input_vector)
        else:
            return predict(right_tree, input_vector)



for employee in test_set:
    print("Predicted : " + str(predict(tree,employee)) + ", Actual : " + 
str(employee[-1]))
```

I'm studying the code to get #TODO here. I do not know. Please help me.

Comment: "How do I ask and answer homework questions? " https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are only asking for the calculation marked #TODO in the code you posted. If you calculate the errors predicted by your model, these error values are sometimes called the "residual errors". You cannot simply sum these, some are negative and some are positive so they might cancel each other. However, if the errors are all squared, then the squared errors are all positive values and can be summed. This is where the term "Residual Sum of Squares" (RSS) comes from. You can use something like "RSS = numpy.sum(numpy.square(errors))" to calculate this value.